Micronaut Http Client: How deserialize empty string to null?
The api we are calling returns empty strings instead of null when the fields are not defined.
This raises an error in Micronaut:
Error decoding HTTP response body: Error decoding JSON stream for type [B]: Error decoding property [List result] of type [class ***.ListResult]: Error decoding property [Reference category] of type [class ***.Incident]: Unexpected token VALUE_STRING, expected START_OBJECT.
This is our incident class (groovy):
@Serdeable
class Incident {
    
    //...
    
    @JsonProperty("u_category")
    Reference category //can be "" (instead of null) or {}
    
    //...
    
}

And ListResult class:
@Serdeable
class ListResult<T> {

    List<T> result

}

Api response:
{"result":[{...,"u_category":"",...}]}

Or
{"result":[{...,"u_category":{"value":"some value"},...}]}

We are using io.micronaut.application version 4.3.6 and io.micronaut.aot version 4.3.6.

You need custom serealizer.
